# How to prevent logging from cluttering your code?

Tags: c#, logging, coding-style

I have been refactoring some of my code, and I can't help but feeling it's very cluttered, complex and confusing. After looking into it more and more, I've begun to notice that the code isn't so much complex as it is verbose.

We're using NLog and providing very verbose output to a debug log, as the application is incredibly prone to failure, and we're trying to be very thorough.

Here's an example of one of the more simple methods

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Zendesk(long? id)
    {
        if (!GlobalVariables.AllSyncSettings.SyncEnabled || !GlobalVariables.AllSyncSettings.ZdSyncEnabled)
            return Json(new { Enabled = "False" });

        if (id == null || id == 0)
            return Json(new { Error = "Missing or malformed ticket ID." }, AG);

        if (CheckZdIdExists((long)id))
            return Json(new { status = "error, in queue." }, AG);

        GlobalVariables.TicketsInQueue.Add((long)id);

        Log("-------------- STARTING NEW CASE [ZENDESK]["+ id +"] --------------");

        var zdHelper = new ZendeskHelpers();
        var zdTicket = zdHelper.GetTicketById((long)id);

        if (zdTicket == null)
        {
            Log("--------------- ENDING CASE [ZENDESK][" + id + "] ---------------");
            GlobalVariables.TicketsInQueue.Remove((long)id);

            return Json(new { Error = "Error fetching ticket" }, AG);
        }

        var sfHelper = new SalesForceHelpers();
        if (!sfHelper.checkTicketOwner(zdTicket))
        {
            Warn(id + " | Case generation not necessary. Ticket doesn't meet criteria.");
            Log("--------------- ENDING CASE [ZENDESK][" + id + "] ---------------");
            GlobalVariables.TicketsInQueue.Remove((long)id);
            return Json(new { success = "case was not generated" }, AG);
        }

        Log(id + " | Generating SalesForce case for Zendesk");

        var sfCase = sfHelper.GenerateCase(zdTicket);
        if (sfCase == null)
        {
            Warn(id + " | Case was not generated successfully. Cannot continue.");
            Log("--------------- ENDING CASE [ZENDESK][" + id + "] ---------------");
            GlobalVariables.TicketsInQueue.Remove((long)id);
            return Json(new { Error = "Case was not generated successfully. Cannot continue." }, AG);
        }

        GetZDAttachments(zdHelper, sfHelper, (long)id, sfCase);

        if (!zdTicket.Status.ToLower().Contains("closed") && ZendeskHelpers.GetCustomField(zdTicket, ZdCustomFields.SfCaseNo) == null)
            zdHelper.SetSfId(zdTicket, sfCase.CaseNumber);

        Log("--------------- ENDING CASE [ZENDESK][" + id + "] ---------------");
        GlobalVariables.TicketsInQueue.Remove((long)id);

        return Json(new { SFCase = sfCase }, AG);
    }
```

Comment: Probably a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: would you be able to reproduce and diagnose the issues you are experiencing without this much logging? if the answer is no, then maybe no change is best. if you don't need this much logging, what do you want to do about it?

Comment: Shouldn't you make the application less prone to failure, then? I might expect to see this level of logging in a temporary debug build on a bug-hunting branch, but never on trunk.

Comment: Unfortunately I basically insert logging anywhere it might be remotely necessary. If there's a possibility for something to fail at all I have a log there to let me pinpoint exactly what happened so I can try to replicate it later.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wish it was that simple, and that's part of the logging. I've put this application through thousands of test cases, and it's been through thousands of real world examples. Yet there are constantly 1-off cases that bring it tumbling down. It synchronizes two third party services, and these services are prone to problems themselves, so I try to handle it with as much confidence as possible.

Comment: Then yeah you've gone too far. Include enough logging to give you a solid idea of how to reproduce (in concert with reproduction steps from your user) but any more than that is noise. You can add it in to your debug build when you reproduce. Or, if you decide that you still want this logging from the outset for whatever reason, then keep it. But it's up to you! Not sure what else you could do other than "keep it" or "lose it"...

Comment: Well, if you *want* to have all of those logging statements throughout the code, then what other choice would you have?  Maybe you can provide more logging information with fewer statements?  For example, things like "start process" and "end process" seem kind of silly when you can get stack traces from exceptions.  Ultimately, your goal should be to make the application more stable.  Just logging everything doesn't fix that.  You might start out with lots of logging statements, but as the application is improved you can remove the superfluous ones.

Comment: The starting and ending tags are there to let me know what the request IDs are, and it allows me to see if it exited gracefully or not. If I can't find an ending tag for a given ID, I know it broke down somewhere.

Comment: @Jdsfighter: `"to let me know what the request IDs are"` - A single log statement at the start of the method does that.  `"I know it broke down somewhere"` - A stack trace does that, which can be captured in a single log statement in a `catch` block.  (Which can also include the ID from the request, eliminating the first log statement if you only need it for error cases.)

Comment: It sure looks like you should just be using a `DelegatingHandler` for logging details of your webapi method, see something like http://arcware.net/logging-web-api-requests/